# how to display response text as html and at the same time send to a php page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, open-flash-chart

calculate.php

```
<form method="post" name="frm_deptcal" id="frm_deptcal"     action="javascript:add(document.getElementById('frm_deptcal'));" >
<span style="font-weight:bold;">Enter your total unsecured* debt </span>
<input type="text" name="txt_principal" id="txt_principal" / >
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Calculate" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(51, 136, 180); color: white; border: 5px solid rgb(120, 176, 205); cursor: pointer;">
</form>
```

in ajax_cal.js i have add() in which XMLHttpRequestObject is created and string is  send
code :

```
var str1= "txt_principal=" + document.getElementById("txt_principal").value;
XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = show;
XMLHttpRequestObject.open('POST', 'value.php', true);
XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
XMLHttpRequestObject.send(str1);
```

In value.php i have done calculation:

```
$principal=$_POST['txt_principal'];    
$x=0.3;
$consumer_mon_pay=60;
$mp_consumer_ans=($principal * $x)/$consumer_mon_pay;
$mp_consumer=round($mp_consumer_ans,3)   ;         
echo $mp_repay."[BRK]".$mp_conloan."[BRK]".$mp_credit."[BRK]".$mp_consumer;
```

and in ajax_cal.js  i have got the response as html and showed in textbox

```
function show()
{
    if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200)
        {
            data = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText.split("[BRK]");
            document.getElementById('txt_mp_repay').innerHTML = data[0];
            document.getElementById('txt_mp_conloan').innerHTML = data[1];   
            document.getElementById('txt_mp_credit').innerHTML = data[2];  
            document.getElementById('txt_mp_consumer').innerHTML = data[3];  

        }
    }

}
```

now my problem is I have to plot a dynamic graph  whose x -axis should be the (txt_mp_repay,txt_mp_conloan,txt_mp_credit,txt_mp_consumer ) values and y -axis will be txt_mp_repay value .the bar graph coding is done using open-flash chart in chart-data.php through which I  have created a static graph.Problem is how to send the response to chart-data.php and  show the whole thing on calculate .php page. Help me ...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear to me what you want to do, but nothing stops you from sending out two ajax-requests at the same time. like

```
var str1= "txt_principal=" + document.getElementById("txt_principal").value;
XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = show;
XMLHttpRequestObject.open('POST', 'value.php', true);
XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
XMLHttpRequestObject.send(str1);    
XMLHttpRequestObject.open('POST', 'chart.php', true);
XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
XMLHttpRequestObject.send(str1);
```